# Auto login or connect Facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

I want to auto login or connect to facebook everytime the user enters my application. If the user logs in with a local account and afterwards clicks on the facebook icon it should automatically login the user.

Is this possible using asp.net mvc or any other .NET framework?

Comment: You should give [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/) a look.